# How to iterate over a macOS app’s windows until a condition is met?

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, macos-high-sierra, xcode9.3

To iterate over all windows in my macOS app, I use [`enumerateWindows(options:using:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1644472-enumeratewindows) like this:

```
NSApplication.shared.enumerateWindows(options: .orderedFrontToBack, using: { 
    (window: NSWindow, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
    if let vc = window.contentViewController as? SomeCustomViewController {
        if someCondition {
            stop = true // “Cannot assign to value: 'stop' is a 'let' constant”
        }
    }
})
```

I want to stop the enumeration when `someCondition` is met, but I can’t set the `UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>` to `true`: Xcode tells me that `stop` is a `let` constant.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stop` is a pointer, you have to set the `pointee`

```
stop.pointee = true
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.